# Query three tables with join

Tags: sql-server

I have five tables that are connected with each other using joins:

- `department` vs `course` -- one to many
- `course` vs `classes` -- one to many
- `classes` vs `section` -- many to many

I want to retrieve the sections the belong to a particular course. I have tried inner join to achieve this but I can not get good results, I get all the sections instead.

```
select sectionname from Section 
inner join Classes on classid=sectionid 
inner join Course on courseid=Classes.fk_course_courseid;
```

[image]

Data contained in the table as shown below. I want to retrieve all the sections the belong to `courseid = 1` or `department id = 1`.

[image]

Comment: Could you please put your table definitions as standard SQL DDL `(CREATE TABLE blah (field_1 type_1,...);` and your data as standard SQL DML `(INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);)`. Either provide it here or in the form of a fiddle - that would be great. Help us to help you! :-) My profile has a few articles on how to ask questions here - you might want to look?

Comment: Based on the info you've provided, there is no link between Section and Course - there is a link from Section to Department and Course to Department so at best you could get all the sections for all the courses in a given department, but there is no relationship defined for section to course so no way to join and retrieve this information.

Comment: yah no link between section and course but the link is through department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sectionname , 
               sectionid 
FROM   section 
       LEFT JOIN classsection 
              ON classsection.fk_section_sectionid = section.sectionid 
       LEFT JOIN classes 
              ON classid = classsection.fk_class_classid 
       LEFT JOIN course 
              ON courseid = fk_course_courseid 
WHERE  coursename = 'School'
```

i just joined `section` and `classses` first and then joined `courses` to see the `department` name which `sections` are belong to which `classes` and it worked kudos

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function and doesn't need parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

i think there should be separate table for `class`,`course`  relation, `Class_Course_Mapping`

Check this (Untested),

```
select sectionname,sectionid
from Section
where exists(
SELECT fk_course_courseid 
FROM    course  
       INNER JOIN classes   
              ON courseid = fk_course_courseid 
INNER JOIN classsection 
ON classid = classsection.fk_class_classid                
WHERE  coursename = 'School' and Section.sectionid=classsection.fk_section_sectionid)
```